# Compiling QT(with QWebKit) 5.x from source as "redist"

Tags: qt, qwebkit

Short story:
I need to compile Qt 5.x with modified QWebKit source as release delivered together with main executable of application (kind of redist package). However I am unable to accomplish this goal.

Long sory:
I made Qt Widgets 5.x application which main part is QWebView, however there is problem with plugin handling. Bug is known and on its way to be corrected (hopefully in full release of 5.3), but for now I need to use ugly workaround which requires modifications to Qt source code, as described [here](https://snusmumriken.qtproject.c.bitbit.net/browse/QTBUG-38067?focusedCommentId=239238&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel), which is just removing eight lines of code.

I followed [compilation guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-building.html), [modified config flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/configure-options.html) and finally I got main QT build

Currently I am in process of yet another horribly long build task (which makes me think that manually null'ing those assert calls in hexeditor would be more productive...)

My steps so far are:
1. extract clean sources (faster than distclean...)
2. configure -release -nomake examples -opensource -opengl desktop
3. make (MSVC or MinGW, do not matter which as long as it will work)

After few failed compilations I finally got expected (or looking like one) result (release libraries).

Next step is QWebKit...

I am trying to follow [this guide](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingQtOnWindows).

Perl, Python and Ruby set up and working (I miss days when compilation required only compiler).
GnuWin32 set and ready.
ICU set and... not working.
To compile Webkit I am using: perl Tools\Scripts\build-webkit --qt --release --minimal (which of course fails at ICU).

It seems that I need to reconfigure and rebuild Qt yet again with ICU support enabled to make it work, but for today I ran out of time to waste for it, hence I am writing here in hope someone will share steps to recompile Qt at first try.

What to do, what to install, what to configure? I am getting crazy from this madness of dependencies already.

Comment: It is all in those links, I would say. I am not sure what else to add.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Problem was with wicked way multistep of configure/make of QT, in short there always was one more error. I "fixed" all my issues by switching to GeckoFX (firefox based control) where plugins all plugins works without any problem.